# Using wrl data in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, import

I'm importing `.wrl` data from matlab that I would like to display. When I'm using the Blender render, I can see the colors as I wanted ( the object already has a material when imported). But when I switch to cycles render (since it produces "nicer" results), my colors disappear.
is there is away to use the cycles render with the imported colors? or how can I make the render look like the cycles render, when sing the blender.

Comment: maybe if you could upload a representative .wrl I could provide a nicer answer.

Comment: I've tried the answer suggested by @zeffii but I could not get it to work. I'm attaching and example, which could be found here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03936112909451894934

Comment: i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The material provided by your importer may need a small adjustment to display the 'vertex_colors' layer when you switch over to Cycles Render engine.

Ideally you should be able to import the *.wrl* while already in Cycles Render engine and let the importer set up the material correctly -- but at present this is not the case.

A solution is to add an `Attribute Node` to the Cycles material Node Tree and write `Col` into the name field. This won't display properly in texture mode, you must set the viewport shading to *Rendered*, or currently you will only see black.

#### steps

1. Import the .wrl as normal
2. Create a node material for the object,

   2a. With the object selected, open a Node Editor  [image]
   2b. set the *Node Tree* view type to Material  [image]
   2c. Tick the box labelled *Use Nodes*
3. Add an *attribute* node, and write 'Col' (without quotes) into it as in the picture.
4. Hook up the output of the *Attribute* node, to the colour input of the *Diffuse BSDF*  node.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide step by step instructions how to do it?

Comment: sure, give me a few minutes